# How can i get the closest match with json using Dart

Tags: dart

I hava a JSON data

```
String sampledata =  '{
                       "data1": {"x": 50,"y": 100,"z": 120},
                       "data2": {"x": 60,"y": 70,"z": 80},
                       "data3": {"x": 50,"y": 60,"z": 100}
                     }';
```

I want to compare it with this

```
int x = 51;
int y = 102;
int z = 120;
```

and the result should be data1
How can I achieve this with dart?

What i tried so far

```
void findClosest(double x,double y,double z){
   final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(sampledata.toString());
   data.forEach((key, value) {
      if(ap1 < value["x"])
        if(ap2 < value["y"])
          if(ap2 < value["z"])
            print(key);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what your problem is? Is it parsing the JSON? Is it the algorithm to find which point are closest to the input point? What have you tried and where did you get into a problem?

Comment: i need an algo i tried to put it in map then i loop it using for each then compare it with < operator but i get the wrong output

Comment: Can you add your non-working implementation to your question? It will make it easier to help you so we don't need to make a solution from scratch.

Comment: sorry i edited my question thanx for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You way to calculate the distance is wrong. You should instead calculate the distance between the two points like:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Which can also be found for 2D points in `dart:math`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-math/Point/distanceTo.html

Based on this I come up with the following solution:

```
import 'dart:math';

class Point3D {
  final String name;
  final int x, y, z;

  const Point3D(this.name, this.x, this.y, this.z);

  double distanceTo(Point3D other) {
    final dx = x - other.x;
    final dy = y - other.y;
    final dz = z - other.z;

    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
  }
}

void main() {
  const list = [
    Point3D('data1', 50, 100, 120),
    Point3D('data2', 60, 70, 80),
    Point3D('data3', 50, 60, 100)
  ];

  const point = Point3D('Search', 51, 102, 120);

  print(list
      .reduce((e1, e2) => e1.distanceTo(point) < e2.distanceTo(point) ? e1 : e2)
      .name);
  // Returns: data1
}
```

Also, instead of `forEach` you can use `reduce` on the list to compare each element to each other and reduce it to a single element. In this case, we want the element in the list where the distance between the `point` variable and point are lowest (Please notice that, that if there are multiple points with same distance we still just return a single point.)